# Should I perform my first oil change at 1000 miles, or when the manual says?

Tags: oil-change, scheduled-maintenance, preventive-maintenance

I've read in various places that you should perform your first oil change on a new car at 1,000 miles or so. But the exact miles are available in the owner's manual.

The owner's manual only states to change the oil every 5,000 miles. Should I go ahead and change it at 1,000 miles, then every 5,000 miles after that? Or should I wait until 5,000 miles for my first oil change?

Comment: But when was that advice written? It might have been true once, but manufacturing is more precise these days and tolerances smaller. There is less debris worn away from high spots and so on than in the past.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The 1000 mile oil change is a holdover from days of yore. It falls into the "my grandfather /father (add appropriate generation) said you should always"... Add what ever urban myth was part of the lesson. Part of the reasoning was due to the Moly-Lube that was part of the engine assembly process. The theory was that the assembly lube was thick enough to clog the oil filter as the hot oil washed it off the bearing surfaces. So after 1000 miles the filter would cease to filter the oil. The improved assembly process and improved chemistry have made this no longer necessary. If it was a concern, the dealer would require it since they  warranty the engine for 60,000 or up to 100,000 miles.

Comment: Not only that, but cars were shipped with "running in" oil, which is thin, and will cause bearing wear if used under load as the engine becomes less "tight". It is however good for mileage. Today's cars have much higher tolerances and looser rings for economy.

Comment: This reminds me of the practice of **warming up a car engine in cold weather** before putting it in drive. I did some research on this last year and discovered that this practice became obsolete in the 1980s. Today, it turns out, the best way to warm up the engine is to actually drive the car.

Comment: @Michael_B These days, "warming up" the car is primarily for passenger comfort rather than the engine.

Comment: @Michael_B Cars do still need to be warmed up for ~30-60 seconds before driving to get the oil heated and distributed before load is placed on the engine. It's letting the car warm up for several minutes that is obsolete with fuel-injected cars. Carbureted engines (uncommon on modern cars, but still around) still require a couple of minutes of warming up before driving.

Comment: @zaen A friend works at a place where the freeway on-ramp is barely 100' from where they park. One very cold night, they did their usual coldstart and gun the car down the ramp up to 70 mph. ***Bang!** Oil pressure zero*.   They sheared off their oil pump shaft.  By the way, carbs have been 100.00% gone since 1996 in the US as it is impossible to have a carbureted car that is OBD II.  And also impossible to hit mid-1990s emission numbers with a carb (without smog devices that would cost way more than EFI).

Comment: @Michael_B Warming up the windscreen can be pretty important though. I have not done this in the past and found it completely frosting up as I was driving.

Comment: @zaen Which "modern cars" still use carburetors? They're (thank god) only used in lawn mowers and Chinese scooters any more over here.

Comment: @towe Alright, "not on modern cars, but still around," happy? There are still plenty of old cars with carburetors on the road, and there are still plenty of motorcycles made with carburetors.

Comment: I don't change the oil on a new car that soon, but I do change the filter 1/2 way into the normal interval.

Answer (score 17):

Do what it says in the owner's manual.

FWIW the manual said the first oil change from new on my current car was at 18,000 miles, not 1,000. I queried that with the dealer and the reply was "yes, that's correct." Nothing bad has happened after 100,000 miles (and it still only burns half a liter of oil in the 18,000 miles between changes, just like it did from new), so I guess the dealer was right.

Comment: Out of curiosity what car do you have? I've never heard of a 18,000 miles recommended interval.

Comment: @GabeWisneski I run a Skoda Octavia (essentially a VW). Using the extended service program with *long life* synthetic oil, the EMS flags a service after 16-17k miles. It's not a fixed interval, perhaps dependant on engine revolutions rather than miles. Synthetic oil does not age as quickly as mineral oil.

Comment: 18k is nothing, I'm at 44k, zero oil change, and zero service. Which, really, isn't an issue, practically. Sure enough, you lose warranty if you don't do service as-written (including, but not limited to oil change). But warranty isn't worth the paper it's printed on anyway, and service tends to _break_ stuff deliberately to keep their business going, so...

Comment: @Damon Wow, is your oil magnetic at this point?

Comment: @Damon please get your car serviced. It could be very dangerous for yourself she other road users.

Comment: @Tim While I do think 44k is far too long to go without an oil change, I fail to see how it's dangerous for anyone.

Comment: @Clonkex not the oil specifically. The lack of any service

Comment: @Tim Ah true, yes that's definitely a risk. Suspension and tyre issues have been discovered numerous times on my car during routine servicing. I don't recommend dealers, however. They're generally pretty awful IMO.

Comment: @WeatherVane My understanding is that the flexible servicing on VAG cars is a combination of things, including an oil quality sensor (not sure how that works). (Next car I buy will likely be Skoda. I currently drive an Audi A3 convertible but I think Skodas tend to be way better value for money. Unfortunately it's harder to find a good-condition Skoda than an Audi, because people spend less money maintaining them... )

Comment: @Clonkex I believe the VAG cars are essentially the same, but priced by the badge. Skoda has IMO better build quality, but VAG shot themself in the foot by not renaming Skoda on buying half the company. To this day, that is a stigma, because previously they were awful. It took comedians 10 years of stale jokes to realise, but Skoda is still no favourite for the company car, where (perceived) status matters.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think they shot themselves in the foot. They did this on purpose, because they get the higher margin for VW brand cars from companies, without losing out price sensitive consumers.

Comment: @Tim: A car that passes the rather pedantic mandatory technical inspection not just with zero faults, but with _zero remarks_ is no threat to others. Not sure where you get this idea from. On the other hand, doing service can greatly increase the risk for yourself and others, depending on how malicious your service shop is. VAG in particular has some very bad apples in the basket around here.

Comment: @Damon so you’re saying your car has undergone the mandatory service? That’s fine then. Your original comment concerned me that it had never been checked

Comment: @Tim: No, I am saying that it has undergone TÜV inspection (not service) as required by the law. Which means, having zero faults and zero remarks, it is _by definition_ (as stated by an authorative institution) safe for use, and no danger to anyone. On the other hand, I've seen service/repair which definitively made a car unsafe for use, and a possibly lethal threat (such as unplugging a previously fixated cable tree for no apparent reason, and letting it dangle near the axis... presumably in the hope of having a recurring customer very soon).

Comment: @Damon A mandatory inspection for new cars is usually required after 4 years of service. If you don't bring your car for maintenance in between (or do the maintenance yourself), you could for instance be running on completely bold tires by that time. A minor leak in the brakes is also likely to manifest itself as a loss of braking efficiency after 4 years, while with regular maintenance it would be just another preventive job.

Comment: @bishop [Actual video of Damon's oil](https://youtu.be/L8cCvAITGWM?t=71)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Bald, not bold. Unless you mean very outgoing tyres...?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yep, that's why I say you get much better value for money with a Skoda. They really pack the features in because they want to change the stigma. Though in my mind, Skoda is an awesome brand because I didn't know anything about it until about 6 months ago when I was considering selling my Audi, so I have a hard time understanding that stigma.

Comment: over in Europe, Skoda sells a couple high-performance models - they're fantastic.  It's funny how car impressions are different in different countries!  An interesting one is Jaguar; in some countries seen as "super lux!" in other countries seen as a kind of rusty brit brand.  Weird stuff !

Comment: The spirit of @Damon 's comment is really correct. In many cases - not all, but many cases - cars are wildly over-serviced.   (Obviously, actual consumables like tires and brake pads and petrol have to be replaced.)

Comment: Incidentally the Skoda Yeti is just an absolutely fantastic machine on every practical and possible level. It was just one of those "perfect products" in its category, like a sienna, an M5, town car, etc.  I don't think they're sold in the US though ?